# How can I add the color in the gray image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a gray image. I would like to add two markers to the image. In which, a marker is blue mark withi color code `(0000FF)` and other marker is red mark `FF0000`. Could you help me to add this mark in the gray image using MATLAB? Note that, each marker has shape is rectangular shape. Thanks

This is my input and my expected output

[image]

[image]

The original image can be download at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz56vbfnofwavbn/11.bmp?dl=0)

Comment: See [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the rectangle function to apply the mask. Now for saving the figure in desired size, you could set the `PaperPositionMode` to `manual` and get the desired image size. The code below also shows different ways to save the figure in different formats.

```
[A, cmap1] = imread('11.bmp');
imshow(A,cmap1);  
hold on; 
rectangle('Position',[45,45,20,10],'EdgeColor','r','FaceColor','r'); 
hold on; 
rectangle('Position',[50,80,30,10],'EdgeColor','b','FaceColor','b'); 
hold off;
f = getframe();
imwrite(f.cdata,'myfigure.bmp');
```

Here is the resulting image:

[image: Here is the resulting image]

Comment: Congrats with first reputation! :)

Comment: Thank Sayantan Ghosh for your code. However, how can i save it as output image with same size with input image

Comment: @xen: the output size is  1125         938           3, meanwhile, input size is 93x118. How can I make 93x118x3 oe 118x93x3?

Comment: @user3051460: You are right, saving the entire figure changes the output size, which can be controlled by playing with the `'PaperSize'` and `'PaperPosition'`. But a simpler hack is to get the frame after `hold off` and then use `imwrite`. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. It is 94x119, instead of 93x118. I think we need remove the first row and first column to obtain original size

Comment: @user3051460: I am sure you can handle that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `insertShape` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.